# Invalid Json Emiited by Backbone 1.2 while saving model?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm newbie to backbone and I have been trying to save my model into a json file.

It works fine, until I try to read the json emitted by my backbone application, and with [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) i discovered that my json is not valid. Here are some details:

My Model (index.htm)

```
     //--------------
    // Model
    //--------------
    app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        prenom:'',
        nom:'',
        adresse:'',
        profession:'',
        mail:'',
        cin:'',
        tel:''

  },
```

My saving function

```
   createTodoOnEnter: function(e){

    app.todoList.create(this.newAttributes());

    // clean input box
          prenom: this.prenom.val('');
          nom: this.nom.val('');
          adresse: this.adresse.val('');
          profession: this.profession.val('');
          mail: this.mail.val('');
          cin: this.cin.val('');
          tel: this.tel.val('');

  },
 newAttributes: function(){


    return {

      prenom: this.prenom.val().trim(),
      nom: this.nom.val().trim(),
      adresse: this.adresse.val().trim(),
      profession: this.profession.val().trim(),
      mail: this.mail.val().trim(),
      cin: this.cin.val().trim(),
      tel: this.tel.val().trim()

    }

  }
```

The json that i get while i'm saving :

```
    {
    prenom: "ramy",
    nom: "dabbabi",
    adresse: "50 rue Fadhel ben achour",
    profession: "Developpeur",
    mail: "ramy@gmai.com",
    cin: 09008585,
    tel: 789456123
}
```

you can notice that there is no double quotes on attributes (prenom,nom...) and that is why my json is not valid.

How can I fix that? Is there any function in backbone witch allows me to define my json format?

Can i format the json sent by the this.model.create function?

Comment: How did you save the model to your json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are calling the [toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) method, if you look at the docs you will see that it doesn't actually return a JSON string

> Return a shallow copy of the model's attributes for JSON
>   stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or
>   for augmentation before being sent to the server. The name of this
>   method is a bit confusing, as it doesn't actually return a JSON string
>   — but I'm afraid that it's the way that the JavaScript API for
>   JSON.stringify works.

You can of course *stringify* the results of the call `JSON.stringify (model.toJSON())`

Additionally if necessary you can always override the backbone methods themselves.

Comment: Thank yout very mutch for your anwser, actually it does send a Valid Json, i was just looking in the wrong place in chrome.